# Faster/bulk activerecord creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord

My application is storing location data from GPS inputs.  When importing a GPX file, a user can have from 500 - 10,000 GPS datapoints.  Right now, I have a model for each trackpoint.  It's working great, but on insert it is SLOW.  30+ seconds for the 10,000 datapoints.  Is there any better way of bulk inserting?

All the time is spent on the SQL side - each insert is quick, but 10,000 add up fast.  Each user might have 100 files, and 100 users == long long insert times.  Not all at once of course.

I'd be happy to change the application architecture if that would help, just not sure what alternatives I have here.  I only ever use the GPS data as a unit.  I never search for one record in the set, so the whole ActiveRecord is overkill.

I'd hate to have to do a whole queue system just to handle this one silly insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been thinking this over, and seems like my two options are serialize a hash to a blob in the DB, or store it elsewhere.  I don't have FS access, but could use S3.

So I suppose I've changed my question.  For storing 100kb objects that are pretty much read-only after creation, any feedback on general principles of S3 vs blob storage?

I think [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662488/would-you-store-binary-data-in-database-or-in-file-system) probably covers what i'm looking for for now!

Answer (score 2):

Use ar-extensions's import method to import them all at once: http://github.com/zdennis/ar-extensions/blob/master/ar-extensions/lib/ar-extensions/import.rb#L49-215

The problem is that if you import each record by doing a `#save`, you are in fact creating one insert statement per row, and calling all of your model's validations. You can instead construct a bigger sql insert statement that pushes all data in at once.