# What are the data type for storing multimedia in RDBM?

Tags: database, types, rdbms, relational

What are the data type for storing multimedia in RDBM?

I can only think of BLOB, TEXT...

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask to get an instruction about how to accept answers.

Answer (score 0):

In general, my advice would be to not store large chunks of binary data in the database. There's very rarely a good reason for it.

See this question for a discussion of the advantages of doing it either way: [Would you store binary data in database or in file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662488/would-you-store-binary-data-in-database-or-in-file-system)

The point that keeps coming back is memory consumption of storing large binary data in the DB.

They also discuss some DB-specific features that might be helpful, such as FILESTREAM in MS SQL Server.

Comment: Some sql server specific datatypes are varbinary and binary. BLOB and image are deprecated.