# What NoSQL store to use for storing images in-memory ?

Tags: nosql, redis

I am trying to understand what NoSQL storage would work best if I need to store images (list size in 6 digits, each image of size 2mb) in-memory for process pipelining ? To my understanding I have considered key-value store like Redis, or should I go for document based storage like CouchDB ?

Thanks.

Comment: 1M * 2MB = 2 TB - it sounds high for in-memory storage ...

Answer (score 0):

As @Didier said, the total size is too high for Redis (even if you shard it across several machines - you'll need a lot of machines and a lot of RAM).

Go for disk-based database (if design dictates saving the binaries in a database - that is [another story](https://stackoverflow.com/a/662501/290343)), but consider using Redis for the most recently used images, using its capabilities of expiring keys, MRU/LRU settings, memory threshold etc.

Comment: Yes thats a lot fo space and eventually the cluster size would be a big fat one. For disk based storage, what's your view on Riak ?